# Combining RandT and MaybeT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have a simple function using `Control.Monad.Random` to create a function which can sample a random number.

```
import Control.Monad.Random       
import Data.Random         

unif_bound :: (RandomGen g, Monad m) => Double -> Double -> RandT g m Double
unif_bound lb ub = getRandomR (lb,ub)
```

And, I run this to generate random numbers in GHCI as:

```
  > gen <- newStdGen
  > runRandT (unif_bound 1.0 3.0) gen
(1.7569726469904563,1700403094 44073136)  
  > runRandT (unif_bound 3.0, 1.0) gen
(1.7569726469904563,1700403094 44073136)
```

However, I would like to modify this code to check that `lb < ub`, and wrap this in a MaybeT. The idea is that sampling where `lb > ub` should return `Nothing`. I realize that this is where monad transformers come in, but I have never used one before and not sure where to start.

For reference, `RandT` is defined as

```
-- | A monad transformer which adds a random number generator to an
-- existing monad.
newtype RandT g m a = RandT (StateT g m a)
    deriving (Functor, Monad, MonadTrans, MonadIO, MonadFix, MonadReader r, MonadWriter w)
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers . You could also just return a `RandT g m (Maybe Double)` -- transformers are sometimes overkill, and sounds like they probably are for your case. But a good opportunity to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize the type of your function quite a bit:

```
unif_bound :: (Random a, Ord a, MonadRandom m) => a -> a -> MaybeT m a
unif_bound lb ub | lb > ub = MaybeT (return Nothing)
                 | otherwise = getRandomR (lb,ub)
```

Note that you could replace `MaybeT (return Nothing)` with `fail ""` because that is how fail is defined in the monad instance for `MaybeT m`, but this isn't very nice. Usage:

```
>runMaybeT $ unif_bound 1 10
Just 2
>runMaybeT $ unif_bound 400 1
Nothing
```

`IO` is an instance of `MonadRandom`, so you don't need to fiddle with `RandT` if you are just testing in the interpreter.